# What is the seeming pattern here?

Tags: pattern-recognition

[image]

So I can see that to go to the input from step 1 involves a addition of 7, which is the 4th term.

But then I can't figure out any link to the 2nd or other steps.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $(3 \times \text{INPUT})+4$

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm coming across dumb but I don't understand.

Comment: $X_{II}=(X_I-10)^2$.

Comment: What I do when I encounter a problem like this, is that I tabulate the values and draw a graph in Excel. I did that for the first two steps and I got these results:
$$
\text{Step 1 is equivalent to adding 7}
$$
$$
\text{Step 2 performs the operation}~x \rightarrow (x-10)^2
$$
etc ... Can you continue from here?

Comment: $X_{IV}=(X_\text{Input}-1)^2$.

Comment: Fundamentalform's comment, while mysterious at first, is actually correct. When you compare Input and Step 3 (you can forget the other steps), indeed the relation is that it performs the operation $x \rightarrow 3x+4$. For example the first number 17 turns into $3\cdot 17 + 4 = 55$. Now you only have to figure out what Step 4 does in relation to the input, and you're done.

Comment: Take the first input number, $17$ multiply it by three and add four and you arrive at $55$. Now repeat that pattern for each of the other inputs and you should arrive at the values in Step 3.

Comment: @fundamentalform, we are not given the Input array, only Step III. But we can work backwards to deduce the Input array, and then get Step IV from my previous comment.

Comment: Ahhhhhh. Okay so each of the steps are related in different ways to the input and not the previous statement. I think I understand now. Thanks everyone.